# How to get result data from success handler on REST API update operation..getting undefined error

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

I used REST API to update list items but I am unable to access the results that is passed to the success handler.  See image below

[image]

How do I gain access to the data?

[image]

Here's the error I get:
[image]

Comment: Is there any updates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Update Success handler, do another Request to get the item which is updated like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
            UpdateListItem(6);

});

 function UpdateListItem(id) {
     var title = $("#Title").val();
     $.ajax
         ({
             url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items('"+id+"')",
             type: "POST",
             data: JSON.stringify
             ({
                 __metadata:
                 {
                     type: "SP.Data.MyListListItem"
                 },
                 Title: title
             }),
             headers:
             {
                 "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                 "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                 "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                 "IF-MATCH": "*",
                 "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
             },
             success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                 ReadListItem(id);
             },
             error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                 console.log(data.responseJSON.error);
             }
         });
 }

 function ReadListItem(id)
 {
     $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items('"+id+"')",
         type: "GET",
         headers: {
             "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
             "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
         },
         success: function (data) {
             console.log(data.d);
             console.log(data.d.Title);
         },
         error: function (error) {
             alert(JSON.stringify(error));
         }
     });
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint REST update does not return the updated item. You will need to make a second request to get the updated item.

Comment: How come I see data that is in the success handler?